# error en laravel 5.2 al iniciar un constructor

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo el siguiente codigo en mi controlador:

```
 public function __construct()
 {
        $this->contrato = CtContrato::findorFail(Route::current()->getParameter('id_contrato'));
 }
```

me sale este error:

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
Call to a member function getParameter() on null

Comment: Gracias, ya hice la modificacion

Comment: coloque eso, pero no reconoce, sale este error: [BadMethodCallException]             
  Method getParameter does not exist.